# How to put more than one overlay label in Openlayers layerswitcher?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wms, web-mapping, boundless-suite

I have two set of layers like 'Public' and 'Private'.Each set has 3 layers. My requirement is, Layer switcher has to show the first set of layers with check-box under the label name 'Public' and second set of layers with check-box under the label name 'Private'. [Not with Option button]. I have tried as shown below:

In Design:

```
<style>
.olControlLayerSwitcher
    {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px !important;
        width: 20em !important;            
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: bold;
        margin-top: 3px;
        margin-left: 3px;
        margin-bottom: 3px;
        font-size: smaller;
        color: #FFFFFF !important;
        background-color: transparent;
        z-index: 10000;
    }
    .olControlLayerSwitcher .layersDiv
    {
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-right: 10px;
        background-color: #1243CE !important;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px !important;
        -moz-border-radius: 5px !important;
        -o-border-radius: 5px !important;
        -ms-border-radius: 5px !important;
        -khtml-border-radius: 5px !important;
        border-radius: 5px !important;
        -khtml-opacity: .8;
        -moz-opacity: .8;
        -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=8)”;
        filter: alpha(opacity=8);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.8);
        opacity: .8;
    }
   .olControlLayerSwitcher .layersDiv .baseLbl
    {
        display: none;
    }
    .olControlLayerSwitcher .layersDiv .baseLayersDiv
    {
        display: none;
    }
   </style>

   <body id="mapBody" onload="init();"> 
      <div id="layerswitcher" class="olControlLayerSwitcher">
          <img id="imgSwitcherClose" alt="" src="Images/Minimize_On.png" />
      </div>
   </body>
```

In Javascript:

```
 //Layer Switcher
var layerSwitch = new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({
    div: OpenLayers.Util.getElement('layerswitcher')
});
osMap.addControl(layerSwitch)

layerSwitch = osMap.getControlsByClass("OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher")[0];
layerSwitch.dataLbl.innerText = "Public"
```

[image]

In that above list I need to add 'Private' label and layers. Please suggest me to implement this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Now I have added more information regarding this..kindly check it

Comment: Are you sure that is all of the openlayers code?

Comment: yes all are openlayers code. There is no additional js..etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenLayers' LayerSwitcher Control doesn't allow to do what you want out of the box. It provides basic layerswitcher functionality and style, but for any custom or advanced use, you have to build your own layer switcher. It's not really hard. Here's a quick example:

Note: Remove OpenLayers LayerSwitcher from your app and add the following function to control the layer visibility:

```
function changeLayerStatus(layerName, visibility) {
    var layers = map.getLayersByName(layerName);
    var layer = layers[0];

    if(!layer) {
        return;
    }

    layer.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

In the HTML, manually add your checkbox and labels. Note that this could be automated, but that's another question. The key here is the call to `changeLayerStatus(layerName, visibility)` on the onclick of the checkbox.

```
 <div id="layerswitcher" class="olControlLayerSwitcher">
   <div id="allLayers" class="layersDiv">
     <div class="dataLbl" style="">Public</div>
     <div class="dataLayersDiv">
       <input name="layer1" type="checkbox" value="layer1" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_Point', this.checked)">OSIM_Point<br>
       <input name="layer2" type="checkbox" value="layer2" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_BoundaryLines', this.checked)">OSIM_BoundaryLines<br>
       <input name="layer3" type="checkbox" value="layer3" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_Boundary', this.checked)">OSIM_Boundary<br>
     </div>
     <div class="dataLbl" style="">Private</div>
     <div class="dataLayersDiv">
       <input name="layer1" type="checkbox" value="layer1" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_Point_private_name', this.checked)">OSIM_Point<br>
       <input name="layer2" type="checkbox" value="layer2" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_BoundaryLines_private_name', this.checked)">OSIM_BoundaryLines<br>
       <input name="layer3" type="checkbox" value="layer3" class="olButton" onclick="changeLayerStatus('OSIM_Boundary_private_name', this.checked)">OSIM_Boundary<br>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```